# Finding values with same value on one field but distinct value on other field

Tags: postgresql

Lets assume I have this postgresql table:

### ProductStore

product_id
store_id
price

How do I query "which products hasn't the same price on every store".

I mean, same value on product_id but distinct value on price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM "ProductStore"
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT price) > 1
```